# Gradle 3.0 Alpha 2 throwing exception while Alpha 1 works fine

Tags: android, gradle

```
   dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
    }
```

Alpha1 works ok for me with Android Studio 3.0 canary 2,
but when I try to use alpha2, I get this exception:

Error:C:\Users\STD1\Documents\STD1\InvistaCultura\invistacultura-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:752 invalid drawable
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:
>     aapt2 compile -o C:\Users\STD1\Documents\STD1\InvistaCultura\invistacultura-android\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug C:\Users\STD1\Documents\STD1\InvistaCultura\invistacultura-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
>     Issues:
>      - ERROR: C:\Users\STD1\Documents\STD1\InvistaCultura\invistacultura-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:752 invalid drawable

and, in values.xml:752, I find this line, which is from a third library:  [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

```
<item name="crop_image_menu_crop" type="drawable"/>
```

What can it be?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue except that the culprit line is

`<item format="integer" name="intercom_faded_is_typing_duration" type="dimen">200
    </item>`
and the build fails with the reason "Invalid dimen"
As you can see the resource is defined already. any ideas?

Comment: is it from ArthurImageCropper? after the "200", is there a space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out that with Gradle plugin 3.0-alpha2 and above, resource values have to be defined, and the library does not define this resource.
For anyone who wants to follow up on this issue and a temporary fix [Undefined Drawable](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/pull/291)
Temporary fix taken from the link
*Before this gets merged and shipped, you can still use the library by declaring in your app resources*

```
<item name="crop_image_menu_crop" type="drawable">@null</item>
```